# Getting Data From a Secondary Partition on a USB Stick

Tags: usb-flash-drive, partition-recovery

I accidently wrote an .img file to my usb stick instead of my sd card using win32diskimager. I think that my data which was on the usb stick wasn't lost as it looked like there was a secondary partition which was the same size as my data. I downloaded minitool partition wizard free and messed around a bit. I think I deleted the primary one and set the other one as primary or something like that but now when I put my usb stick into the computer the computer doesn't recognise that anything happened (I can't get to it in the file explorer). Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are in for a hard battle.

The primary problem you will most likely face is that the partition table is stored in the first 512 bytes of the disk, and as that has been overwritten there is no trivial way to find the partitions.

IF YOU VALUE YOUR DATA, BEFORE DOING ANYTHING BELOW - BACK IT UP - IE MAKE A BIT COPY OF THE  USB STICK SO YOU CAN RECOVER IT IF THINGS GET WORSE.

You should look at the "[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)" suite of tools - this is free data recovery software.    The first tool to run is "Testdisk", which will scan through the disk and try and find partitions.  With some luck it may be able to recognise the filesystem and deduce the partition.    If this fails, you can use Photorec (part of the suite) to try and find individual files (mainly photos) and recover what it can.